# User usercontrol buttons in multiple views

Tags: wpf, user-controls

`I am working on a WPF application (MVVM)
I have a user control(uc1) that has four buttons. cancel,accept,exit
I am going to use this control in multiple views.

I need to cancel button to revert the changes what user will make in propertygrig

```
user control:
<UserControl x:Class="WPF.CustomControl.RadPropertyWindowButtons"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="45" d:DesignWidth="700">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Uid="radpropertybuttons" Height="39" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="74,0,-108,0">
            <Button x:Name="Cancel"                          
            Command="{Binding radpropertyCancel}" >
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="Accept"                                       
             Command="{Binding radpropertyAccept}">
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="Exit"                                        
                Command="{Binding radpropertyExit}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
            </Button>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

view:

```
 <Grid Height="564" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">

            <telerik:RadLayoutControl
                Name="PropertyGridContainer"    
                Orientation="Vertical">
            </telerik:RadLayoutControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <customcontrol:RadPropertyWindowButtons x:Name="ucPropertyButtons" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Loaded="RadPropertyWindowButtons_Loaded" />
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

in view model

```
  public ICommand radpropertyCancel { get; set; }
radpropertyCancel = new ViewModelCommand(execradpropertyCancel);
 private void execradpropertyCancel(object obj)
        {
            this.RevertToOriginalData();

        }
```

how to clear the PropertyGridContainer and bind with the data that we get from RevertToOriginalData`

I do it like this if i do from code behind if i use click event but how to do it with command.

```
this._viewModel.RevertToOriginalData();
this.PropertyGridContainer.Items.Clear();
this.PropertyGridContainer.Items.Add(this._viewModel.myGrid);
this.ViewModel.IsDirty = false;
```

Comment: Work with a copy of your object instead of the original. Then you just bin your new object rather than reverting. You can validate before you decide to commit changes by replacing the original with the new object.

Comment: Maybe you like to explain what exactly you are doing. Some believe you want to restore the state of data models while others (me) understand you want to restore UI layout. Please render the context/scenario of your problem to get everybody on the same page. This should be the first information a good question provides. If your question is about data models then please show them as they are the integral part of the question and answer.

Comment: *"I need to cancel button to revert the changes what user will make in propertygrig"* - What kind of *changes*? Data or layout? Also explain to the people what the RadLAyoutControl is about.

Comment: Been a while since I use telerik controls but I think there are already built in context menus allow the user to serialise and persist layout. I can't recall whether you can also edit ui properties. But this usercontrol seems to be include code intended to  revert a viewmodel to model data  _viewModel.RevertToOriginalMoldData();  Which makes me think the property grid id editing viewmodel data and this is a generic view intended to edit any viewmodel properties in a propertygrid.  Personally,. I would edit a copy and then  commit if valid.

Comment: @Andy am working with copy of data...i am getting the data original data but not able to bind it with the propertygridcontainer.

Comment: @BionicCode radlayoutcontainer just contains a radproperty grid.

Comment: So you modify a data model and want to restore the previous state on cancel? Then why don't you give this valuable information and why didn't you chose to not show related code? Please update your question to provide necessary details. The radlayoutcontainer  is pretty irrelevant in this context. The radpropertygrid is relevant. You should completely revisit your question.

Comment: I think your property grid should be in the usecontrol. Or your user control should be a contentcontrol so the propertygrid or any editing control can become it's content.

Comment: Thank you all i decided to go with onclick event instead of command as i need to get the ui elements. I have implemented in code behind and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this._viewModel.myGrid` is wrong design if `myGrid` is really a `Grid` ( a UI element). Your view model classes must never handle UI elements or participate in/implement UI logic.

Data changes are always handled outside the view (where the data lives). Layout on the other hand is always the domain of the view.
If you want to revert the layout changes made by the user, you must do this completely in the view (code-behind).
To accomplish this, a parent control (e.g., `Window`) that hosts both, the `RadPropertyWindowButtons` and the `RadLayoutControl`, should expose the related commands as routed commands.

Then in the command handlers you save (serialize) the layout before edit (or alternatively on accept/after edit) and restore (deserialize) it in case the edit procedure was cancelled. The `RadLayoutControl` exposes a related API to help with the serialization.

Now, that the implementation of the custom control no longer depends on the explicit view model class type, the `RadPropertyWindowButtons` has become fully reusable in any context.
In general, to enable reusability of controls they must express their (data) dependencies as dependency properties, that are later bound to the current `DataContext`. The internals of the reusable control simply bind to these dependency properties (instead of binding to an explicit `DataContext` type). Otherwise they are only "reusable" with a particular `DataContext`.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```xml
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static RoutedUICommand CancelEditLayoutCommand { get; } = new RoutedUICommand(
    "Cancel layout edit and revert to previous state",
    nameof(MainWindow.CancelEditLayoutCommand),
    typeof(MainWindow));

  public static RoutedUICommand AcceptLayoutCommand { get; } = new RoutedUICommand(
    "Accept the current layout",
    nameof(MainWindow.AcceptLayoutCommand),
    typeof(MainWindow));

  private Dictionary<RadLayoutControl, bool> IsInEditModeTable { get; } 
  private string SerializedLayout { get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.IsInEditModeTable = new Dictionary<RadLayoutControl, bool>();
    
    var cancelEditLayoutCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(MainWindow.CancelEditLayoutCommand, ExecuteCancelEditLayoutCommand, CanExecuteCancelEditLayoutCommand);
    _ = this.CommandBindings.Add(cancelEditLayoutCommandBinding);
    
    var acceptLayoutCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(MainWindow.AcceptLayoutCommand, ExecuteAcceptLayoutCommand, CanExecuteAcceptLayoutCommand);
    _ = this.CommandBindings.Add(acceptLayoutCommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteCancelEditLayoutCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = e.Parameter is RadLayoutControl targetControl 
      && this.IsInEditModeTable.TryGetValue(targetControl, out bool isTargetControlInEditMode) 
      && isTargetControlInEditMode;

  private void ExecuteCancelEditLayoutCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var targetControl = (RadLayoutControl)e.Parameter;
    RestoreLayout(targetControl);
    this.IsInEditModeTable[targetControl] = false;
  }

  private void CanExecuteAcceptLayoutCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = e.Parameter is RadLayoutControl targetControl
      && this.IsInEditModeTable.TryGetValue(targetControl, out bool isTargetControlInEditMode) 
      && isTargetControlInEditMode;

  private void ExecuteAcceptLayoutCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var targetControl = (RadLayoutControl)e.Parameter;
    SaveLayout(targetControl);
    this.IsInEditModeTable[targetControl] = false;
  }

  // Instead of handling the SelectionChanged event I recommend
  // to introduce another routed command that allows the user to put the RadLayoutControl into edit mode (by setting the RadLayoutControl.IsInEditMode accordingly).
  // Aside from an improved UX this would provide a better flow or trigger to kickoff the serialization
  private void OnLayoutControlSelectionChanged(object sender, LayoutControlSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  { 
    var targetControl = sender as RadLayoutControl;
    if (this.IsInEditModeTable.TryGetValue(targetControl, out bool isTargetControlInEditMode)
      && isTargetControlInEditMode)
    {
      return;
    }
  
    isTargetControlInEditMode = e.NewItem is not null;
    if (isTargetControlInEditMode)
    {     
      SaveLayout(targetControl);
    }
   
    this.IsInEditModeTable[targetControl] = isTargetControlInEditMode;
  }

  private void SaveLayout(RadLayoutControl targetControl)
    => this.SerializedLayout = targetControl.SaveToXmlString();

  private void RestoreLayout(RadLayoutControl targetControl)
    => targetControl.LoadFromXmlString(this.SerializedLayout);
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <telerik:RadLayoutControl Name="PropertyGridContainer"
                              IsInEditMode="True" 
                              telerik:RadLayoutControl.SerializationId="PropertyGridContainerID"
                              SelectionChanged="OnLayoutControlSelectionChanged" />
    <customcontrol:RadPropertyWindowButtons TargetControl="{Binding ElementName=PropertyGridContainer}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**RadPropertyWindowButtons.xaml.cs**

```cs
class RadPropertyWindowButtons
{
  public RadLayoutControl TargetControl
  {
    get => (RadLayoutControl)GetValue(TargetControlProperty);
    set => SetValue(TargetControlProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "TargetControl",
    typeof(RadLayoutControl),
    typeof(RadPropertyWindowButtons),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));
}
```

**RadPropertyWindowButtons.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="Cancel"                          
            Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.CancelEditLayoutCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=TargetControl}" />

    <Button x:Name="Accept"                                       
            Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.AcceptLayoutCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=TargetControl}" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

See [Save/Load Layout](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radlayoutcontrol/features/save-load-layout#saveload-layout) for more advanced scenarios.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251616/discussion-on-answer-by-bioniccode-user-usercontrol-buttons-in-multiple-views); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.